# Efficient python chat server

Tags: python, sockets, chat, asyncore

I am now writing a unicast chat server model, the flow will be as follows:

- Sender send out message to the chat server, in the message the server also specify the message recipient id
- The chat server will route the message to the right client, based on the recipient id

I implemented the chat server model using python standard library asyncore. I found that the CPU goes up, once the client connect to the server (1% vs 24%). I believe the performance is limited by the looping of the handle_write function.

Is there a better (e.g. more efficient) framework to accomplish my chat server requirement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really a question, but look at [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course we'd need actual code to debug the problem. But what you're mainly asking is:

> Is there a better (e.g. more efficient) framework to accomplish my chat implementation?

Yes. It's generally accepted that `asyncore` sucks. It's hard to use as well as being inefficient. It's especially bad on Windows, because `select` especially sucks on Windows.

So, yes, using a different framework will probably make things better.

Unfortunately, an SO question is not a good place to get recommendations for frameworks, but I can throw out a list of usual suspects: [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com), [monocle](https://github.com/saucelabs/monocle), [gevent](http://gevent.org), [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/), [tulip](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/).

Alternatively, if you're not worried about scalability to more than a few dozen clients, just about performance at the small scale, using a thread per client (or even two threads, one for reads and one for writes) and blocking I/O is incredibly simple.

Finally, if you're staying up to date with Python 3.x, there's a good chance that 3.4 will have a new and improved async I/O module that's much more efficient and much easier to use than `asyncore` (and it will almost certainly be based on `tulip`). So… the best solution may be to get a time machine and go forward a few months. (Or, if you're a reader searching for this answer in the future, look in the standard library under [IPC](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) and guess which module is the new-and-improved async I/O module.)

Answer (score 1):

I just read from a web, talking about the efficiency between different python web servers ([Link](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers)).

I think I will use gevent as it is very efficient (seems).